# combineLatest subscribe not firing

Tags: angular, rxjs

I tried like this but not getting into anything in console.log. please help me

```
private someVar: Observable<any>;

this.someVar = combineLatest(
   this.someService.todos,
);

this.someVar.subscribe(([todos]) => {
  console.log(todos);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you update the data in the `this.someService.todos`?

Comment: That means that at least one of the todos has never emitted.

Comment: @JBNizet is correct, a `combineLatest` Observable will only emit once **all** of the inner Observables have emitted at least once. What is the behaviour you're looking for?

Comment: Assuming `this.someService.todos` is an array of Observables, you can do `.pipe(tap(_ => { debugger; })` or `.pipe(tap(_ => { console.log('x fired'); })` to see which one of the observable do not emit.